# URL's in search results page are wrong and not the URL of the article assigned menu item

Tags: joomla3.9

I have Joomla 3.9.21 which has SEF URL's enabled.

All works perfectly, but search results page.

For example, this is the SEO link to an article (which is assigned a menu option whose root option is called "proyectos"):

```
https://www.example.com/proyectos/thearticle.html
```

So far, so good. However, when I do a search where that article is on the results, the link of the article is this:

```
https://www.example.com/component/content/article/thearticle.html?catid=13&Itemid=101
```

How can I get rid of `component/content/article` part and replace it by the menu option the article is assigned to? In this case, root menu option is called "proyectos".

If I disable SEF, I realized that this URL is for the menu option that is assigned to the article:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=160
```

And when searching, this is the actual URL for that article in results page:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15:thearticle&catid=13&Itemid=101
```

Maybe the `catid=13&Itemid=101` part is interfering. The `catid` is the category the article was assigned to and `Itemid` 101 is the home menu item. This ID is strange. For some reason, com_search module is not finding the Itemid associated to the article, 160 in this case.

Regards

Jaime

Comment: Whenever you have a question that directly pertains to Joomla OR would benefit from the support of a community with intimate knowledge of the CMS and its extensions, then you should post your question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange instead of Stack Overflow.  You may wish to flag this question to be migrated by moderators from here to JSE.  JSE is not getting enough daily questions -- https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842?phase=beta

Comment: Thanks, I have created the question in JSE. I hope I have a soon answer, however, I am currently downloading the whole site using Netbeans so that I will try to figure this out by myself if there is no explanation somewhere,